# ASP.Net GridView Sorting

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sorting

I have a grid view with AllowSorting set to true. I get an event onsorting when a sortable header is clicked on. the handler has a parameter "GridViewSortEventArgs e" which has a SortDirection property on it. regardless of how many times you click on the same heading, the SortDirection is always Ascending. I think I'm missing something, like a way to tell the grid "now you are sorted based on column one and in ascending order", so that next time the grid sees a click on the "column one" heading, it decides to go descending.

any help appreciated.
Cheers,
Ali

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, 
I listened to balexandre and took the viewState approach. I think I shouldn't be doing this, but there seem to be no better way atm and I have to ship today...

thanks again, great community.
Cheers,
Ali

Comment: The ViewState approach is the correct way to go.  This feature does NOT work with any datasource other than an asp:SqlDataSource object, according to my research.